# Como conecto um banco de dados do HeidiSQL no Visual Studio usando os pacotes do Report Viewer?

Tags: c#, mysql, banco-de-dados

Segue o código do meu BD do **HeidiSQL**:

```
CREATE DATABASE ProdPacote;  
USE ProdPacote;

CREATE TABLE Produto(  
ID_Produto INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  
Nome VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,  
Descricao VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,  
Preco DOUBLE NOT NULL);  

CREATE TABLE Pacote(  
ID_Pacote INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  
Nome VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,  
ID_Produto VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,  
Quantidade INT NOT NULL,  
Data_entrada DATE NOT NULL,  
Data_saida DATE NOT NULL);  


CREATE TABLE Produto_Pacote(  
ID_Produto_Pacote INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  
Data_Hora DATE NOT NULL,  
FK_ID_Produto INT NOT NULL,  
FK_ID_Pacote INT NOT NULL,  

CONSTRAINT Produto_Pacote  
FOREIGN KEY (FK_ID_Produto)  
REFERENCES Produto (ID_Produto),  

CONSTRAINT Pacote_Produto  
FOREIGN KEY(FK_ID_Pacote)  
REFERENCES Pacote(ID_Pacote));
```

Esse erro em específico não me deixa continuar:

> MENSAGEM DE ERRO: Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root'
>   using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access
>   denied for user "root" @"localhost" (using password: YES)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Mensagem de Erro: Failed to open a connection to the database "Cannot obtain provider factory for data provider named 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. " Check the conection and try again.]

[image: Some updating commands could generated automatically. The database returned the following error: You have a usuable connection already]

Comment: A mensagem é de falha no login... você tem certeza de que está utilizando as credenciais e apontando para o host correto?

Comment: Obrigado, eu consegui arrumar o erro de Login, mas agora quando eu vou concluir a conexão com o banco, aparece o seguinte Erro: Failed to open a connection to the database "Cannot obtain provider factory for data provider named 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. " Check the conection and try again.   Segue imagem acima, na postagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu tive o mesmo problema há uns meses atrás, segui esse processo e resolveu, detalhe que usei versões específicas e logo não garanto que funcione em versões diferentes.
O processo abaixo resolve os seguintes erros:

1. *"Some updating commands could not be generated automatically. The database returned the following error: Unexpected Error"*
2. *Erro: Failed to open a connection to the database "Cannot obtain provider factory for data provider named 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. " Check the conection and try again.*

SOLUÇÃO PROPOSTA:

1. Desinstale  "Connector /Net" e "Mysql for Visual Studio", se instalado.
2. Instale o "Mysql for Visual Studio v1.2.7" . NOTA: Instale o Mysql para Visual Studio antes do Connector / Net.
3. Instale "Connector / Net v6.9.8".
4. Tente realizar o processo que precisa.

Infelizmente trabalhar com Mysql no VS é bem complicado, muitos erros só se resolvem com versões especificas e muitas vezes o problema até resolve, porém aparece outro.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui passar daquela etapa, porém agora quando vou selecionar as tabelas no Report, aparece o seguinte erro:  Some updating commands could generated automatically. The database returned the following error: You have a usuable connection already.   Segue imagem acima.

Comment: Olá, então esse é um problema claro do mysql for visual studio e do Connector/Net. Há um tempo atrás ouvi relados desse problema aqui e se tratava da versão. Aparentemente nem todas versões funcionam no Visual Studio 2017. Tente refazer o processo acima, só que com as versões que coloquei.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Consegui sim, muito obrigado. Realmente eram as versões dos conectores que eu estava utilizando, eu usei as que você mostrou ali em cima e deu tudo certo!